# How to turn off iTunes Store localisation?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store, internationalization, language

The iTunes Store has an annoying habit of localising song metadata based on the system language: for instance, if I have my system language set to English but buy from the Japanese iTunes store, the song name "以心伝心" will instead appear as "Ishindenshin" in the store and metadata of the downloaded file.

Logging out of the store, changing the system language to Japanese, and then logging back in corrects the issue, at least until the system language is changed back.

I tried setting iTunes to always open in Japanese as follows:

```
defaults write -app iTunes AppleLanguages -array ja
```

but while the rest of the app obeys this nicely, the store doesn't, and insists on continuing to localise content.

Anyone know if a similar setting exists to set the store language/localisation without changing the entire system language?